# Magento 2 cloud getDefaultStore return null object when multiple store

Tags: magento2.3, magento-enterprise, magento2.4.4, magento-cloud

I have cloud enterprise project with multi website. We are facing issue of null object is returned from getDefaultStore method.

I have created one admin role and given full access but assigned only selected website scope which we need.
[image]

And we using magento default login as customer functionality with that role and facing this error.and unable to login successfully.
[image]

I checked the default code and try to debug the issue but not get any luck.When we pass here getDefaultGroupId as static for that particular website then it's working.

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getDefaultStoreView()
    {
        $defaultWebsite = $this->websiteRepository->getDefault();
        $defaultStore = $this->getGroup($defaultWebsite->getDefaultGroupId())->getDefaultStore();
        return $defaultStore ?: null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Vikas kalal**, for that try the below code hope it's working for you.

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
protected $storeManager;
public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
  $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
        
public function getDefaultStoreView()
{
   $websiteId =1;
   // get default store id of website 1
   $storeId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($websiteId)->getDefaultStore()->getId();
}
```